# Is it possible to configure custom headers for AVPlayerItem URLRequest?

Tags: swift, video-streaming, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have HTTP Live Stream URL and I use AVPlayerItem to play the stream. I can init AVPlayerItem only with URL but i need to send some custom HTTP Header Fields in request so that the server responds.

1) Is it possible to configure custom headers for AVPlayerItem URLRequests?

2) If not, what other options can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are creating `AVURLAsset` you can add an option `AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey` and provide your HTTP headers. The code should look similar to:

```swift
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options:["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": yourHttpHeaders])
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

Comment: Is possible to request timeout?